# \hline produces "undefined control sequence"

Tags: hline

I'm at a loss why the proper code like this one would produce "undefined control sequence" at every \hline:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Maybe it has something to do with my imports?

```
\usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2019}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for professional tables
\usepackage{float} %to fix figures



\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % various math stuff
\usepackage{wrapfig}  % Allow wrapping of text around figures
\usepackage{mdwlist}  % Make list items closer together: itemize*, enumerate*
\usepackage{sidecap}  % For putting caption beside figure
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm,amsbsy} % for bold symbols

% \usepackage{subcaption}  % apparently contains errors
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but regarding your comment on the  `subcaption` package. This line causes an error massage because the `subfigure` package and the `subcaption` package can not be used together. However, as the `subfigure` package is considered obsolete, you might want to use either the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package instead.

Comment: By the way, your example code can be drastically reduced to the following: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 7):

Commenting out:

```
\usepackage{arydshln}
```

solves the issue.

Comment: If you want to continue using the `arydshln` package, load the `array` package just before loading `arydshln`.